# How to setup a "typical" USB auto mounting on Gnome?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, automounting

On arch-linux, when gnome is installed - it doesn't setup a USB auto mounter by default.

While [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks) has examples of different auto-mounters,
how would I setup a typical auto-mounter (what gnome would use on ubuntu/redhat - for example).

I'm not sure what components to enable `gvfs volume monitor`, `udiskd` or `udiskie`.

---

If I run udiskie manually, I see USB drives in nautilus, I can also mount via the command line.